# Model property gets reset

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Issue: Model property gets reset when I make a call to a service, I suspect that is not the actual call but an issue with scopes.

Background: the application is a simple application that renders a list of resources acquired from a API. The user is then able to to interact with said resources (share through our form, view in more detail, etc.). The user is able to share one or more resources by enabling the sharing more and selecting multiple residences or by clicking a sharing button. In both of these cases, a selected property is assigned to the object. If the user clicks on the sharing button(individual), the sharing mode is automatically enabled and the user is prompted for the necessary details.

The issue that I'm experiencing is that when a resource is selected, enabling the sharing mode (or a filtering mode) the newly edited 'selected' property gets reset to its initial state.

The code is composed of several directives and services. The list directive is responsible for rendering and acting on source list. A controls directive, which is able enable the sharing and filtering modes. A selection service that acts as storage for the current selections. A controls service, which acts as storage for several application settings.

The list can be filtered by using the url (hard filter) and by using the controls in the controls directive (soft filter). Upon loading, the list requests the resource through the other service and populates the list once the promise is resolved. At this point, the data is cleaned up and it is filtered(hard) if necessary.

**ResidenceListDirective.js**

```
function residenceList($filter, $timeout, $window, ResidenceService, ModalService, ControlsService, filterByIds, SelectionService, $stateParams, config) {
  return {
    templateUrl: 'views/residence_list.html',
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function($scope) {

      var getControls = function() {
        return ControlsService.getAll();
      };

      $scope.$watch(getControls, function(newValue) {
        $scope.selectionMode = newValue.selectionMode;
        if ($scope.allResidences) {
          setSoftFilter(newValue);
        }
      }, true);

      function setSoftFilter(filterValue) {
        if ((filterValue.currentFilter !== null) && (filterValue.currentFilter !== $scope.currentFilter)) {
          $scope.currentFilter = filterValue.currentFilter;
          changeFilter();
        } else {
          $scope.softFilteredResidences = angular.copy($scope.hardFilteredResidences);
        }
      }

      ResidenceService.getAllResidences()
        .then(function(data) {

          $scope.allResidences = data;
          $scope.hardFilteredResidences = angular.copy($scope.allResidences);

          // callback for when the data has finished loading
          successHandler();

        });

      function changeFilter() {
        // if the currentFiler is a number, lets filter by bedroom count
        $timeout(function() {
          if (angular.isNumber($scope.currentFilter)) {
            $scope.softFilteredResidences = $filter('filter')($scope.hardFilteredResidences, {bedrooms: $scope.currentFilter}, true);
          } else {
            // if current filter we have to filter by the input given
            // TODO: parse the string given and use that to filter instead of hardcoding value here
            ...
          }

        }, 500);
      }

      // take all of the prices and run them though the filter in
      // order to filter all the prices in the start and not on each
      // digest cycle.
      var cleanData = function() {
        angular.forEach($scope.hardFilteredResidences, function(residence) {
          // I can set the default here
          //residence.selected = false;
        });
      };

      /**
       * callback for when the data finishes loading.
       */
      var successHandler = function() {
        cleanData();
        $scope.hideList = false;
        setSoftFilter(ControlsService.getAll());
      };

      $scope.setSelection = function(residence) {
        console.log(residence);
        var selection = $filter('filter')($scope.softFilteredResidences, {selected:true}, true);
        SelectionService.setSelection(selection);
      };

      $scope.shareSingle = function(item) {
        item.selected = true;
        // // scroll up
        $window.scrollTo(0,0);
        //item.selected = true;

        SelectionService.setSelection([item]);
        console.log(SelectionService.getSelection());
        ControlsService.toggleMode('email');
        $scope.reAddSelection();
        console.log('clicked');

      };

      $scope.getSelected = function() {
        return $filter('filter')($scope.softFilteredResidences, {selected: true}, true);
      };
    }
  };
}

angular.module('ResidenceRenderer').directive('residenceList', residenceList);
```

**ControlsService.js**

```
function ControlsService() {
  var controls = {
    emailMode: false, // controls the state of the sharing form
    filtersMode: false, // controls the state of the filters
    selectionMode: false, // controls whether the selection boxes on each row is visible       currentFilter: null,
    currentMode: null
  };

  ...

  function setMultiple(values) {
    for (var value in values) {
      controls[value] = values[value];
    }
    return controls;
  }

  function toggleMode(desiredMode) {
    var newStates = {};
    if (desiredMode === 'filter') {
      newStates = {
        emailMode: false,
        selectionMode: false,
        filtersMode: true,
        currentMode: 'filter'
      };
    } else if (desiredMode === 'email'){
      newStates = {
        emailMode: true,
        selectionMode: true,
        filtersMode: false,
        currentMode: 'email'
      };
    } else {
      newStates = {
        emailMode: false,
        selectionMode: false,
        filtersMode: false,
        currentMode: null
      };
    }
    setMultiple(newStates);
  }

  return {
    toggleMode: toggleMode,
    setMultiple: setMultiple
  };
}

angular.module('ResidenceRenderer').service('ControlsService', ControlsService);
```

**SelectionService.js**

```
function SelectionService() {
  var selection = [];

  function setSelection(selectedObjects) {
    selection = selectedObjects;
  }

  function getSelection() {
    return selection;
  }

  return {
    getSelection: getSelection,
    setSelection: setSelection
  };
}
angular.module('ResidenceRenderer') .service('SelectionService', SelectionService);
```

I have gathered a few clues but I have no idea what is happening. When I don't set a default `selected` property, then either make it `true` or `false`, then enable the filter or sharing mode, the property disappears. If I assign a default selected value, upon toggling filter or sharing mode, the property defaults to its initial value.

Comment: Consider significantly (!) reducing the example code to a minimum that still reproduces the problem - read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Most people would have time or patience to parse through your code. And the added benefit is that you most likely solve the issue yourself or at the very least understand it much better

Comment: yeah I removed quite a few methods before publishing, I 'll see what else I can trim. Thanks you

Comment: Typically, if one needs to scroll, it's too much

Comment: guessing somewhere you passing reference instead use angular.copy()